# Java Fraction mapping to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using apache's BigFraction class, which basically uses BigInteger for numerator and denominator. now I need to store these values in the database, and I need to ensure they are as accurate as possible due to the nature of the data.

I set the sql server to have columns for numerator and denominator, which are set to type numeric(35, 0).

Now the problem im having is that once in while my calculations exceed this value and I end up with an exception of data truncation.

Any suggestions on the type to use in sql server and ensure a decent amount of precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that numeric is the largest numeric type in Sql Server [MSDN on datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) and as you have found you need to define how many figures after the decimal point upfront.

Thus you have to store BigNumbers as strings - varchar(4000) to keep all significant figures and note that it you need more than 3999 then you will have to split over several columns, You might also be able to store directly as binary in `varbinary` columns but you won't be able to easily see what s stored in the db. If your numbers always have less than 35 significant figures in numerator and denominator you could save in two numeric fields.